# How to calculate Floquet exponents?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to apply Floquet theory to analyse the stability of the periodic solutions for a system of differential equations. I understand the theoretical portion, but how can I actually find the Floquet exponents? I searched a lot but I couldn't find any simple example. Would someone help me with an example for a two by two system of ODEs? I will be grateful.

PS: For example my differential equation is:
$$\dot{x}=\mu-d x,$$
$\mu$ and $d$ are periodic functions of t.
I am adding more work that I did on this problem. I made it homogeneous equation by using a transformation $y=x-\frac{\mu}{d}$. The equation becomes:
$$\dot{y}=-d y$$
Solving this gives me: $$y=c_0 e^{\int{-d(t)dt}}$$
Now the $$\phi(t)=e^{\int{-d(t)dt}}$$ and $C=1$. Here $\phi(t)$ is the fundamental matrix. This means that the Floquet multiplier is $1$. Is it so?

Comment: I saw another post on floquet multipliers which was answered by Anon but the in that question, the differential equation was very simple because it was it was homogeneous, i guess.

Comment: Do you have access to the book "An introduction to Dynamical Systems" by Arrowsmith and Place? See section 2.6 and the corresponding problems, especially 2.6.5, which has an excellent example. Regards

Comment: Thank you very much @Amzoti I will look into this book.

Comment: Also, do these notes [*Complex Eigenvalues*](http://www.math.wsu.edu/math/faculty/schumaker/Math512/512F10Ch2B.pdf), [*Floquet*](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~ward/teaching/m605/every2_floquet1.pdf) help, [*Periodic Linear Systems*](http://www.math.byu.edu/~grant/courses/m634/f99/lec17.pdf)? Regards

Comment: @Amzoti I have another question: If i have an equation like this:
$$\dot{x}=\mu g(x)-d x$$. Where $\mu$ and $d$ are periodic in time. The function $g(x)$ is a Sigmoidal Hill function ($g(x)=\frac{x^n}{x^n+K^n}$) where $n$ is anything like 1,2,3... and K is a constant. How can I prove that there exists a periodic solution to this equation? I could not find anything relevant to my problem and I am really struggling with it. Sorry if I am being repetitive.

Comment: @Amzoti I looked into the book by Arrowsmith and i am reading it. Would you please have a look at the work i did that i mentioned in my question above. Does it seem right to you?